# Evaluate a certain derivative

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, polynomials, complex-numbers, rational-functions

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be pairwise distinct complex numbers and $\{l_1,\dots,l_n\}$ a vector of natural numbers such that $l_1+l_2+\dots+l_n=N$. Let
$$ h_j(x)=\prod_{i\neq j,i=1,\dots, n} (x-x_i)^{-l_i}. $$

Assume $|x_i|\leq 1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ and $|x_i-x_j|\geq \delta>0$ for all $i\neq j$.

**Question**: bound (from above) the successive derivatives of $h_j$ at $x_j$, i.e. $$ |h_j^{(t)}(x_j)|,\qquad t=0,\dots,l_j-1 $$ in terms of $N,n,\delta,t$.

(For motivation, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114972)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leibniz formula applied to the logarithmic derivative of $h_j$ and an induction on $t\geqslant0$ lead to the conclusion that, for each $t\geqslant0$, there exists some universal polynomial $P_t$ of degree $t$ such that
$$
|h^{(t)}_j(x_j)|\leqslant P_t(N)\,\delta^{-N-t}.
$$
More precisely, $|h_j(x_j)|\leqslant \delta^{-N}$ and the identity
$$
h'_j(x)=h_j(x)\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{\ell_i}{x-x_i},
$$
yields the recursion formula
$$
h^{(t+1)}_j(x)=\sum_{k=0}^t{t\choose k}h^{(k)}_j(x)\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{(-1)^{t-k}(t-k)!\ell_i}{(x-x_i)^{t-k+1}},
$$
hence
$$
|h^{(t+1)}_j(x_j)|\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^t{t\choose k}|h^{(k)}_j(x_j)|\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{(t-k)!\ell_i}{|x_j-x_i|^{t-k+1}},
$$
implies that
$$
|h^{(t+1)}_j(x_j)|\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^t{t\choose k}\frac{P_k(N)}{\delta^{N+k}},\frac{(t-k)!N}{\delta^{t-k+1}}.
$$
In other words, one can choose $P_0(N)=1$ and, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$
P_{t+1}(N)=N\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{t!}{k!}P_k(N).
$$
This yields $P_t(N)=N(N+1)\cdots(N+t-1)$, and finally,
$$
|h^{(t)}_j(x_j)|\leqslant\frac{\Gamma(N+t)}{\Gamma(N)\,\delta^{N+t}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey, I wrote a short note incorporating your proof, based on [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114972). Would you like to be credited in addition to a usual reference? Plz contact me (see my user page)

Comment: The usual reference `http://math.stackexchange.com/a/248559` to this MSE page is enough.